# Paragraph in PDFbox

Tags: pdfbox

I have a requirement to change the PDF file using iText to PDFbox. I have following doubts:

1. How to generate a paragraph in PDF box? (new paragraph in iText)
2. How to give color for the font in PDFbox? (`Font.BOLD`, `new Color(79, 129, 189))` in iText)

Can someone give me an advice how to solve those problems?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you found the answer for this yet or not....

As far as I've heard, PDFBox doesn't know line breaks and you'll have to format the text and position it yourself with the `moveTextPositionByAmount` method.

This is how I write something and change the font and color:

```
PDFont font = PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD;
PDPageContentStream contentStream =
    new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true,true);
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(font, size);
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(Color.BLUE);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(x,y);
contentStream.drawString(message);
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.close();
```